# Can't start Thunderbird: No protocol specified

Tags: debian, thunderbird, xorg

I'm on Debian testing (buster), and I'm getting an error when starting Thunderbird. It's weird, cause I can start Firefox and other X applications with no problem. Here's the error:

```
$ thunderbird 
No protocol specified
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Error: cannot open display: :0
```

My `$DISPLAY` is set to `:0`:

```
$ echo $DISPLAY
:0
```

**Update:** Interestingly, this problem occurs when I'm booted into Debian's 4.14.0-2 kernel, but not when booted into a 4.15.0-rc7 kernel that I compiled myself.

Answer (score 0):

Do the two kernels differ regarding apparmor settings? See Debian Bug #882122: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882122 (thunderbird: Thunderbird can't connect to X server, fails to start)